# Python rpdb: Telnet to remote session break with saying [connection closed by foreign host]

Tags: python, session, telnet

I am trying to debug server side code using python rpdb. rpdb opens a telnet session at `port 4444` on server side, I am able to telnet to the `port 4444` successfully, however after some time approximately 1 minute my telnet session automatically closes by saying

```
connection closed by foreign host.
```

Any suggestion, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`rpb` does not open the port until it hits a break point. If you telnet in too early the system is likely to hang up on you.